# Load only one ID element from another website

Tags: jquery, iframe

I know I can do something like this

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Load remote content into object element</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="siteloader"></div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $("#siteloader").html('<object data="http://tired.com/">');
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

And to load another web site in my page,but the problem is that on that url i have one element, and I​ want to get only specific ID content from that website like ID `#sidebar-wrapper` is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

It is typically not possible to load content from another website and read it using JavaScript due to browser security restrictions. You will probably need a server-side script to download the data first on the server and then serve it to your client.